# How to make terminal shortcut with this code in it?

Tags: command-line, wine, winetricks

Hi i am not good at terminal shortcuts or anything like that but if someone can give me instructions to make these to commands to a shortcut that will be awesome

```
cd "/home/owner/.wine/dosdevices/c:/Program Files/Riot Games/League of Legends/RADS/system"
```

and

```
WINEDEBUG=+ntdll wine "rads_user_kernel.exe" run lol_launcher $(ls ../projects/lol_launcher/releases/) LoLLauncher.exe
```

Comment: I think that your first command should be `cd "/home/owner/.wine/dosdevices/c:/Program\ Files/Riot\ Games/League\ of\ Legends/RADS/system"` instead.

Comment: Not true, this will work perfectly well as long as the path is quoted as shown in the question. `cd foo\ bar` and `cd "foo bar"` are both correct and will work.

Comment: @Lucio You don't escape spaces when you have something quoted.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to make it a permanent command that works no matter what user (root or your own account) you're using, then this is the simplest. Open a text editor and make a new document. Save it to your home folder as the name of your command (example: mycommand). Then in the document enter the following

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "/home/owner/.wine/dosdevices/c:/Program Files/Riot Games/League of Legends/RADS/system"
WINEDEBUG=+ntdll wine "rads_user_kernel.exe" run lol_launcher $(ls ../projects/lol_launcher/releases/) LoLLauncher.exe
```

Save it. Now open Terminal and do the following:

```
chmod +x mycommand
sudo cp ~/mycommand /usr/bin/mycommand
```

Now just restart the Terminal or enter the command `bash`. You should now be able to run your custom script at anytime by using it's name (example: `mycommand`)

Comment: I think that this commands won't work. Read [my comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/276965/how-to-make-terminal-shortcut-with-this-code-in-it#comment347272_276965) below.

Comment: @Lucio You don't need to escape spaces if you have the address enclosed in quotes.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you mean by shortcuts. I *think* you mean bash [aliases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_%28command%29). If so, add these lines to your `$HOME/.bashrc`:

> alias league='cd "/home/owner/.wine/dosdevices/c:/Program Files/Riot Games/League of Legends/RADS/system"'
>   alias lol='WINEDEBUG=+ntdll wine "rads_user_kernel.exe" run lol_launcher $(ls ../projects/lol_launcher/releases/) LoLLauncher.exe'

You can now run these ciommands by opening a terminal and typing `league` or `lol`. You can change the names to whatever you want, the general format of bash aliases is

```
alias <alias name>='<command to run>'
```

Comment: I think that this commands won't work. Read [my comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/276965/how-to-make-terminal-shortcut-with-this-code-in-it#comment347272_276965) below.

Comment: @Lucio it will work because the path is "quoted". Both `cd foo\ bar` and `cd "foo bar"` work perfectly well.

Comment: @terdon Also if you run `alias <alias name>='<command to run>'` in a Terminal session you'll get a Temporary Alias that will be disposed when you close that Terminal. Useful if you're just doing an extra long command a lot during a single session.

Comment: I open too many terminals at the same time for that. Probably why my .bahsrc has 54 aliases :).

Comment: @terdon The more aliases you have the slower your commands will be executed because it has to check back each time to check through all the aliases. Just an FYI. Another problem with Aliases is that they are User Dependent, meaning they only apply to one user.